# Google Maps Script - Changing the static info with variables from the database loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, google-maps-api-2

Ok, so I am trying to figure out how to include the below javascript/jquery google maps script in the loop. What I am wanting to do is replace the static information in the script and replace them with the variables outputted by the DB loop. I also have pagination setup to limit the query to 20 per a page. Please see here: http://clients.beckin.com/prince-corp/test/dealer-locator.php

I would like this script to only contain the information for each address that is listed in the table which is looped from the DB. How in the world can I do this?

**Update:**
I have updated my Google Maps Script. Please see below. I was able to pass the variable into the script. However, how can I loop the variable in my database loop and contain them into the

```
  addresses =   [
        "<?php echo $myAddress; ?>",
        ];
```

section? Each page will loop with 20 address. How can I do that in the script?

http://clients.beckin.com/prince-corp/test/map_test.php

```
<?php
$myAddress= "117 Mitchell Blvd, Gadsden, 35904"; 
?>
```

**Javacript Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) { 

    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setUIToDefault();

    // Create a base icon for all of our markers that specifies the
    // shadow, icon dimensions, etc.
    var baseIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
    baseIcon.shadow = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png";
    baseIcon.iconSize = new GSize(20, 34);
    baseIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(37, 34);
    baseIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(9, 34);
    baseIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(9, 2);

    // Creates a marker whose info window displays the letter corresponding
    // to the given index.
    function createMarker(point, index) {
      // Create a lettered icon for this point using our icon class
      var letter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + index);
      var letteredIcon = new GIcon(baseIcon);
      letteredIcon.image = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + letter + ".png";

      // Set up our GMarkerOptions object
      markerOptions = { icon:letteredIcon };
      var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);

      GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(addresses[index]);
      });
      return marker;
    }


  // ====== Create a Client Geocoder ======
  var geo = new GClientGeocoder(); 

  // ====== Array for decoding the failure codes ======
  var reasons=[];
  reasons[G_GEO_SUCCESS]            = "Success";
  reasons[G_GEO_MISSING_ADDRESS]    = "Missing Address: The address was either missing or had no value.";
  reasons[G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS]    = "Unknown Address:  No corresponding geographic location could be found for the specified address.";
  reasons[G_GEO_UNAVAILABLE_ADDRESS]= "Unavailable Address:  The geocode for the given address cannot be returned due to legal or contractual reasons.";
  reasons[G_GEO_BAD_KEY]            = "Bad Key: The API key is either invalid or does not match the domain for which it was given";
  reasons[G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES]   = "Too Many Queries: The daily geocoding quota for this site has been exceeded.";
  reasons[G_GEO_SERVER_ERROR]       = "Server error: The geocoding request could not be successfully processed.";
  reasons[403]                      = "Error 403: Probably an incorrect error caused by a bug in the handling of invalid JSON.";

  var j=0;
  // ====== Geocoding ======
  function getAddress(search, next) {
    geo.getLocations(search, function (result)
      { 
        // If that was successful
        if (result.Status.code == G_GEO_SUCCESS) {
          // Lets assume that the first marker is the one we want
          var p = result.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates;
          var lat=p[1];
          var lng=p[0];
          if(j == 0)
          {
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lng), 15);
          }

            var latlng = new GLatLng(lat, lng);
            map.addOverlay(createMarker(latlng, j));

        }
        j++;
        next();
      }
    );
  }


  // ======= An array of locations that we want to Geocode ========
  addresses =   [
        "<?php echo $myAddress; ?>",
        ];

  // ======= Global variable to remind us what to do next
  var nextAddress = 0;

  // ======= Function to call the next Geocode operation when the reply comes back

  function theNext() {
    if (nextAddress < addresses.length) {
      getAddress(addresses[nextAddress],theNext);
      nextAddress++;
    }
  }

  // ======= Call that function for the first time =======
  theNext();

}

// display a warning if the browser was not compatible
else {
  alert("Sorry, the Google Maps API is not compatible with this browser");
}

</script>
```

Comment: The code you have listed is [Google Maps Javascript API v2 code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference), that version of the API was officially deprecated on May 19, 2010. The original deprecation period has been extended from May 19, 2013 until November 19, 2013. As of this date, all applications requesting v2 will be served a special, wrapped version of the v3 API instead. We expect this wrapped version of the API will work for most simple maps, but we strongly encourage you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Maps JavaScript API before this date.

Comment: Ok thanks! Thanks for letting me know that. But how can I still generate the code from my database? For looking at version 3 it looks like they are using coordinates. However, I need to be able to just loop my addresses inside the script?

Comment: Please have a look at my updated notes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this :) Here is my solution with making google maps dynamically from a database query. I ended up just doing it with arrays. Hope this helps others ;)

**PHP**

```
$thisAddress[$i] = mysql_result($result, $i, 'address');
$thisCity[$i] = MYSQL_RESULT($result,$i,"city");
$thisState[$i] = MYSQL_RESULT($result,$i,"state");
$thisZip[$i] = MYSQL_RESULT($result,$i,"zip");

<?php
$thisAddress0 = "$thisAddress[0], $thisCity[0], $thisState[0] $thisZip[0]"; 
$thisAddress1 = "$thisAddress[1], $thisCity[1], $thisState[1] $thisZip[1]"; 
$thisAddress2 = "$thisAddress[2], $thisCity[2], $thisState[2] $thisZip[2]"; 
$thisAddress3 = "$thisAddress[3], $thisCity[3], $thisState[3] $thisZip[3]"; 
$thisAddress4 = "$thisAddress[4], $thisCity[4], $thisState[4] $thisZip[4]"; 
$thisAddress5 = "$thisAddress[5], $thisCity[5], $thisState[5] $thisZip[5]"; 
$thisAddress6 = "$thisAddress[6], $thisCity[6], $thisState[6] $thisZip[6]"; 
$thisAddress7 = "$thisAddress[7], $thisCity[7], $thisState[7] $thisZip[7]"; 
$thisAddress8 = "$thisAddress[8], $thisCity[8], $thisState[8] $thisZip[8]"; 
$thisAddress9 = "$thisAddress[9], $thisCity[9], $thisState[9] $thisZip[9]"; 
$thisAddress10 = "$thisAddress[10], $thisCity[10], $thisState[10] $thisZip[10]"; 
$thisAddress11 = "$thisAddress[11], $thisCity[11], $thisState[11] $thisZip[11]"; 
$thisAddress12 = "$thisAddress[12], $thisCity[12], $thisState[12] $thisZip[12]"; 
$thisAddress13 = "$thisAddress[13], $thisCity[13], $thisState[13] $thisZip[13]"; 
$thisAddress14 = "$thisAddress[14], $thisCity[14], $thisState[14] $thisZip[14]"; 
$thisAddress15 = "$thisAddress[15], $thisCity[15], $thisState[15] $thisZip[15]"; 
$thisAddress16 = "$thisAddress[16], $thisCity[16], $thisState[16] $thisZip[16]"; 
$thisAddress17 = "$thisAddress[17], $thisCity[17], $thisState[17] $thisZip[17]"; 
$thisAddress18 = "$thisAddress[18], $thisCity[18], $thisState[18] $thisZip[18]"; 
$thisAddress19 = "$thisAddress[19], $thisCity[19], $thisState[19] $thisZip[19]"; 
?>
```

**Google Map Script:**

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=YourKeyHere"  type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) { 

    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setUIToDefault();

    // Create a base icon for all of our markers that specifies the
    // shadow, icon dimensions, etc.
    var baseIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
    baseIcon.shadow = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png";
    baseIcon.iconSize = new GSize(20, 34);
    baseIcon.shadowSize = new GSize(37, 34);
    baseIcon.iconAnchor = new GPoint(9, 34);
    baseIcon.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(9, 2);

    // Creates a marker whose info window displays the letter corresponding
    // to the given index.
    function createMarker(point, index) {
      // Create a lettered icon for this point using our icon class
      var letter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + index);
      var letteredIcon = new GIcon(baseIcon);
      letteredIcon.image = "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + letter + ".png";

      // Set up our GMarkerOptions object
      markerOptions = { icon:letteredIcon };
      var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);

      GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(addresses[index]);
      });
      return marker;
    }


  // ====== Create a Client Geocoder ======
  var geo = new GClientGeocoder(); 

  // ====== Array for decoding the failure codes ======
  var reasons=[];
  reasons[G_GEO_SUCCESS]            = "Success";
  reasons[G_GEO_MISSING_ADDRESS]    = "Missing Address: The address was either missing or had no value.";
  reasons[G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS]    = "Unknown Address:  No corresponding geographic location could be found for the specified address.";
  reasons[G_GEO_UNAVAILABLE_ADDRESS]= "Unavailable Address:  The geocode for the given address cannot be returned due to legal or contractual reasons.";
  reasons[G_GEO_BAD_KEY]            = "Bad Key: The API key is either invalid or does not match the domain for which it was given";
  reasons[G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES]   = "Too Many Queries: The daily geocoding quota for this site has been exceeded.";
  reasons[G_GEO_SERVER_ERROR]       = "Server error: The geocoding request could not be successfully processed.";
  reasons[403]                      = "Error 403: Probably an incorrect error caused by a bug in the handling of invalid JSON.";

  var j=0;
  // ====== Geocoding ======
  function getAddress(search, next) {
    geo.getLocations(search, function (result)
      { 
        // If that was successful
        if (result.Status.code == G_GEO_SUCCESS) {
          // Lets assume that the first marker is the one we want
          var p = result.Placemark[0].Point.coordinates;
          var lat=p[1];
          var lng=p[0];
          if(j == 0)
          {
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(lat, lng), 15);
          }

            var latlng = new GLatLng(lat, lng);
            map.addOverlay(createMarker(latlng, j));

        }
        j++;
        next();
      }
    );
  }


  // ======= An array of locations that we want to Geocode ========
addresses =   [
        "<?php echo $thisAddress0; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress1; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress2; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress3; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress4; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress5; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress6; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress7; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress8; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress9; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress10; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress11; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress12; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress13; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress14; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress15; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress16; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress17; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress18; ?>",
        "<?php echo $thisAddress19; ?>",
        ];

  // ======= Global variable to remind us what to do next
  var nextAddress = 0;

  // ======= Function to call the next Geocode operation when the reply comes back

  function theNext() {
    if (nextAddress < addresses.length) {
      getAddress(addresses[nextAddress],theNext);
      nextAddress++;
    }
  }

  // ======= Call that function for the first time =======
  theNext();

}

// display a warning if the browser was not compatible
else {
  alert("Sorry, the Google Maps API is not compatible with this browser");
}

</script>
```